# IOS Swift 4 UIView isHidden with tapGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I got a weird problem.

I made a simple Single View App with a TabBarController, added Subviews to the first Item (`ViewController`) and made them hidden with the interface builder properties.

Now I want to recognize taps within the entire view to make them visible one after another and hide them again in the end.

The `gestureRecogniser` is placed from the interface builder. All outlets are properly connected and do work.

Anyway, when I tap the first time the `UIView`s won't show but the `isHidden` property is set correctly. I've tried many things and searched SO but nothing really helped in this case. Force-Wrapping everything into the main thread doesn't help either and shouldn't make a difference in this case anyway.

This is my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var step = 0

  @IBOutlet weak var firstViewOutlet: UIView! // properly connected
  @IBOutlet weak var secondViewOutlet: UIView! // properly connected
  @IBOutlet weak var thirdViewOutlet: UIView! // properly connected
  @IBOutlet var tapRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer! // properly connected

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector (self.tapAction(_:)))
    print("viewDidLoad")
    // Tried to hide them manually on load. Didn't work so I switched back to the interface builder property (checkbox)
    // hideSubviews()
  }
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
  }

  @objc func tapAction(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer){
    print("Tapped: \(self.step)") // Always works and shows the correct step value
    switch self.step {
    case 0:
      print("Untap should show! \(self.step)") // Shows after first tap
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.firstViewOutlet.isHidden = false
        print("Value of first view state: \(self.firstViewOutlet.isHidden)") // shows false but visible after SECOND tap
        self.step += 1
      }

      // Alternative doesn't change anything
      // self.firstViewOutlet.isHidden = false

    case 1:
      print("Upkeep should show! \(self.step)") // Shows second first tap
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.secondViewOutlet.isHidden = false
        print("Value of second view state: \(self.secondViewOutlet.isHidden)") // shows false but visible after THIRD tap
        self.step += 1
      }

      // Alternative doesn't change anything
      // self.secondViewOutlet.isHidden = false

    case 2:
      print("Draw should show! \(self.step)") // Shows after third tap
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.thirdViewOutlet.isHidden = false
        print("Value of third view state: \(self.thirdViewOutlet.isHidden)") // shows false but visible after FOURTH tap
        self.step += 1
      }

      // Alternative doesn't change anything
      // self.thirdViewOutlet.isHidden = true

    case 3:
      print("Draw should clear! \(self.step)")
      hideSubviews() // works after FIFTH tap

      // Alternative doesn't change anything
      // self.firstViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      // self.secondViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      // self.thirdViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      // self.step = 0
    default:
      return
    }
  }

  func hideSubviews(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.thirdViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      self.firstViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      self.secondViewOutlet.isHidden = true
      self.step = 0
    }
  }
}
```

Funny enough, after the first cicle everything works as espected.
I even tried to add `view.layoutIfNeeded()`, `view.layoutSubviews()`, `view.setNeedsDisplay()` and `view.setNeedsLayout()` to the outlets and to `self.view` but it didn't change anything either.

Any suggestions are appreciated. I bet it's a small and stupid bug that I just can't see.

It seems it's any UI change. Even changing the labels colors doesn't work on the first tap.

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new project (Single View Application).
- Click ViewController, Editor->Embed in->Tap Bar Controller
- Click Library icon, drag Container view to ViewController
- Set [hidden] property for this Container view to true in Interface Builder
- Create Outlet from Container View to ViewController
- Click Library icon, drag Tap Gesture Recognizer to ViewController (not into container view!)
- Create Outlet from Container View to ViewController
- Copy my code or write from scratch

Comment: Why are you using `DispatchQueue.main.async` here?  What do you want it to do that just setting the values does not?

Comment: As I mentioned in my post setting it directly doesn't work either.

Comment: I implemented your exact code above in a new project with the viewController embedded in a UITabBarController and I am not able to reproduce your results.  The first view appears on the first tap and so on.

Comment: Now that is strange. I'll try it with a new project and update if it works too. Weird...

Comment: I created a new project, did everything from scratch. Same behaviour.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you've provided in the question.  It must be something in how you are using it in your project.  How are you setting up the UITapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183098/discussion-between-akaino-and-vacawama).